# AmazonServiceException: User is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:DescribeTable Status Code: 400; Error Code: AccessDeniedException

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-iam, amazon-cognito

I had originally thought that this issue was due to mismatching regions, but after changing the region, I'm still coming across the following error when trying out an Amazon AWS sample found here:

[DynamoDBMapper](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/tree/master/DynamoDBMapper_UserPreference_Cognito)

```
 AmazonServiceException: User: arn:aws:sts::[My Account
 ARN]:assumed-role/Cognito_AndroidAppUnauth_DefaultRole/ProviderSession
 is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:DescribeTable on resource:
 arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:[My Account ARN]:table/test_table (Service:
 AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: AccessDeniedException;
 Request ID: BBFTS0Q8UHTMG120IORC2KSASVVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG)
```

Everything is more or less the same, the only things I've changed have been changing the `DBclient` region to `US_EAST_1`, where my test table is hosted and modifying the Constants file using the info from the 'Amazon Cognito Starter Code' page that is generated through following the Cognito get started documentation.

[sdkforandroid-cognito-auth](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforandroid/developerguide/cognito-auth.html)

For my `Cognito_AndroidAppUnauth_DefaultRole` role policy I modified the default mobile analytics and sync service permission to also include access of all actions on all tables, existing or not:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "CognitoPolicy",
            "Action": [
                "mobileanalytics:PutEvents",
                "cognito-sync:*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "DynamoDBPolicy",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "dynamodb: *"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

So why is it claiming that it doesn't have permission when the correct region is used and the Unauth policy should allow for table access?

EDIT: Stacktrace when calling a method on the DynamoDB resource (create table), should it prove useful

```
   com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException: User: arn:aws:sts::[My Account ARN]:assumed-role/Cognito_AndroidAppUnauth_DefaultRole/ProviderSession is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:CreateTable on resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:[My Account ARN]:table/test_table (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: AccessDeniedException; Request ID: SDELNSMLO10EV7CM2STC1R9RU3VV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG)
            at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(Unknown Source)
            at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(Unknown Source)
            at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(Unknown Source)
            at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.createTable(Unknown Source)
            at com.amazonaws.demo.userpreferencesom.DynamoDBManager.createTable(DynamoDBManager.java:72)
            at com.amazonaws.demo.userpreferencesom.UserPreferenceDemoActivity$DynamoDBManagerTask.doInBackground(UserPreferenceDemoActivity.java:99)
            at com.amazonaws.demo.userpreferencesom.UserPreferenceDemoActivity$DynamoDBManagerTask.doInBackground(UserPreferenceDemoActivity.java:85)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Worked with an Amazon engineer and it turns out the problem was in the policy configuration:

```
"dynamodb: *"
```

should be

```
"dynamodb:*"
```

It's amazing what a space can do.

Comment: Cool, was just about to post that - great that AWS support is highly available too :)

Comment: Yeah, GitHub issues are much better than the AWS forums, at least for working with sample resources provided by Amazon. They probably wouldn't help if it was some other crazy code of your own design since it wouldn't be relevant to the sample projects. XP

Comment: @KurtWagner: Where is policy configuration located?

Comment: @AnasAzeem Should be in the IAM console. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/ManagingPolicies.html

Answer (score 0):

In my case, my table name included a "/" character, which is invalid. Removing the "/" character from the table name resolved the issue.

Answer (score -1):

You can instead assign permission to the lambda's role like this:

[image]