# AccessDeniedException on aws when i'm trying to raise a support ticket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

i just referred to this question [AmazonServiceException: User is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:DescribeTable Status Code: 400; Error Code: AccessDeniedException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24765256/amazonserviceexception-user-is-not-authorized-to-perform-dynamodbdescribetabl) which has similar error. but it doesn't help me.

I'm getting this error when i try to raise a support ticket:

```
Invalid Input

User: arn:aws:iam::44324457964845364:user/testetest is not authorized to perform: support: (Service: AWSSupport; Status Code: 400; Error Code: AccessDeniedException; Request ID: 65dq34fedq234rde9-adqwef443432fasd-13q4wf4qqrf-9q34fewq431-9fasdff3wefw43efw3eas5b4)
```

this is the link i'm using https://console.aws.amazon.com/support

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See: [Accessing AWS Support](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awssupport/latest/user/getting-started.html#accessing-support)

Unless you are a power user or administrative user, by default you do not have the privilege to raise a support ticket. Have your IAM administrator add an IAM policy like this so that you can raise a support ticket.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": ["support:*"],
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

It is same as the IAM policy document: AWSSupportAccess
[image: AWSSupportAccess]

Comment: Thanks. This was difficult to find for some reason, here's the reference about it: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awssupport/latest/user/getting-started.html#accessing-support